# What is a path in neo4j cypher v2.0 and higher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I read in the [neo4j 2.0 cypher-refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.0/cypher-refcard/)

that

> Paths are no longer collections, use `nodes(path)` or `rels(path)`.

What is a path now? Why the change? What consequence for path MATCHing does the change have, for example?

Comment: If you try a post to the transaction end point and check out the data I thin you will see that they are ordered collections of maps of node and relationship properties. `[ {node}, {rel}, {node}, {rel}, ... {node}]`

Comment: @DaveBennett so they are not collections any more but now they are ordered collections?

Comment: A path is a path.  @DaveBennett answers what they are from the JSON perspective.  Inside of cypher they're a special kind of object, which you can access in various ways (e.g. through nodes and rels).  This I find more clear and intuitive; if it was to be a collection, what would it be a collection of?  Inevitably mixed types (e.g. node rel node rel).  Better that it should be its own object type to discourage people from doing things like indexing into even numbered items making certain assumptions.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits - your comment feels a lot like an answer to me.  I feel enlightened - of course a path is a path with different access methods.

Comment: Moving this from comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path is a path. @DaveBennett answers what they are from the JSON perspective. Inside of cypher they're a special kind of object, which you can access in various ways (e.g. through nodes and rels). This I find more clear and intuitive; if it was to be a collection, what would it be a collection of? Inevitably mixed types (e.g. node rel node rel). Better that it should be its own object type to discourage people from doing things like indexing into even numbered items making certain assumptions.

Expanding on the previous answer, this (I think) further makes sense because of the syntax cypher uses for path binding, i.e.

`MATCH p=(a)-[r]-(b) RETURN p`.

Clearly in this example `p` is something special.  The syntax pretty clearly indicates that `a` has to be a node, and `r` is definitely a relationship.  Paths just aren't either of those things.

From a programming language perspective, it's good for "collections" to be uniformly typed.  E.g. a programmer can know how to deal with a `Collection<String>`, this means each item in the collection plays by the semantic rules of a `String`.   Making a path a collection would then be problematic, because it can't be a collection of any one type.  When iterating through a path/collection, what would you do with each item?  The answer is it would depend on what the item is, which tends to make for messy code.

Again, better to have paths be their own thing.   Want to iterate over all of the nodes in the path?  That's what `nodes(p)` is for, which will give you a uniformly typed collection.   Extra bonus that it makes your cypher code more readable.

In some ways I'm "back-explaining" what the neo4j devs did.  I didn't make this design decision, and I wasn't involved in it, so I'm not giving you the neo4j official answer why.  This is just my explanation for why the design decision was (IMHO) a very good idea.  It follows design patterns you see everywhere else, with certain advantages.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Thanks to a related answered post, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655824/neo4j-cypher-trying-to-understand-identifiers-and-collections-in-match-and-wher , I think I figured it out in which cases there are collections of paths (not to be mixed up with the fact that a path is NOT a collection in neo4j 2.0 and higher), e.g. the returned `c` in `MATCH p = ()-[]-() WITH COLLECT(p) AS c RETURN ;`

Comment: Yes -- that also makes sense, I see the confusion.  What you say here would be a *collection of paths*, it wouldn't make a *path a collection*.  Ah, software development.  Swap the order of two words, and you're in a  different world.  :)