# Trying to understand identifiers and collections in MATCH and WHERE

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to understand to what kind of cypher "data structure" certain identifiers or expressions correspond to, depending on how and where they are used.
Below I list examples I encountered. Please tell me if I got it right (in the comments) or if I am missing something.

```
MATCH (a:MYTYPE { label:'l_a' })
// a corresponds to a collection of nodes

MATCH (b:MYTYPE { label:'l_b' })
// so does b

MATCH p=(a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)-[sp12:CF]->(c)
// p corresponds to a collection of paths
// a and b correspond to a collection of nodes 
// (or does the previous MATCH of a and b change something?)
// sp1 corresponds to a collection of collections of relationships
// sp12 corresponds to a collection of relationships
// c corresponds to a collection of nodes

WHERE ( p = ... )
// Here, the p corresponds to a path, i.e. there must be a path or (I don't know) on the right side of the =
WHERE ( a = ... )
// a corresponds to a node, i.e. there must be a node on the right side of the =
WHERE ( sp1 = ... )
// sp1 corresponds to a collection of nodes, i.e. there must be a collection of relationships on the right side

//BONUS:
WHERE ( (e)-[sp2:CF*]->(f) ) = ...
// there must be a collection of collections of paths on the right side of the =
```

Comment: On the right side of ` p = `  would have to be a path too, but I'm not sure they implement equality, if they don't, I'd compare `nodes(p)` or `rels(p)`

Comment: I presume what you mean when you say "a is a collection of nodes" is that when you `RETURN a` you end up with rows of nodes in the client? Otherwise your assumption is not correct and things like `a` and `b` are a single node per returned row.

Comment: Michael: Yes your assumption is correct. I thought the fact that "ending up with rows" meant the returned value was a collection. But now I realize it is not.

Comment: @MichaelHunger : would you suggest modifying my incorrect question or leave it like this with the correcting answers/comments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the easiest way to answer all these questions is by passing identifiers to functions that will throw an error telling you what it expected and what it actually received. I think you should also be careful about how you use the word collection, as it is not correct.

## Nodes, Relationships, Paths

`MATCH (n) RETURN n;`

`n` is a `Node`.

`MATCH ()-[r]-() RETURN r;`

`r` is a `Relationship`.

`MATCH p = ()-[]-()`

`p` is a `Path`.

## Collections

`MATCH (n) WITH COLLECT(n) AS c RETURN c;`

`c` is a `Collection<Node>`.

`MATCH ()-[r]-() WITH COLLECT(r) AS c RETURN c;`

`c` is a `Collection<Relationship>`.

`MATCH p = ()-[]-() WITH COLLECT(p) AS c RETURN c;`

`c` is a `Collection<Path>`.

## Variable Length Paths

`MATCH p = ()-[r*..2]-() RETURN p, r;`

`p` is a `Path`.

`r` is a `Collection<Relationship>`.

And to refer to your specific example:

`MATCH p = (a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)-[sp12:CF]->(c)`

`p` is a `Path`.

`a` is a `Node`.

`sp1` is a `Collection<Relationship>`.

`b` is a `Node`.

`sp12` is a `Relationship`.

`c` is a `Node`.

And I'm not sure what you're asking about the `WHERE` clauses. Perhaps you can clarify with an edit to your question.

Comment: As pointed out by Michael's comment above, I was wrong to assume that returning an identifier and ending up with a number of rows means that this identifier represents a collection. This is why I added the WHERE clauses. In fact, exactly as you suggest, I tried several things in the WHERE clauses to get info from the error messages. The infos I got were different compared to my (wrong) assumptions about identifiers in the MATCH part. If I understand it correctly now, there is no difference regarding the type (e.g. node, collection of node) of an identifier if used in MATCH or in WHERE, right?

Comment: Right. An identifier's data type does not depend on which Cypher keyword it follows.

Comment: This is the best question and answer about Cypher that I have seen in a while. But just to let @stackoverflowwww know that there are some mysteries left to explore, and with reference to the questions about comparisons, check out [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/gvttx9), with default graph and minimally modified query.